# how do i take in arraylist and file into my action performed savemap method?

Tags: java, file, arraylist

This is my savemap method.

```
public void savemap (File file,ArrayList<Cell> obstacles)
  {


    if (file == null) {         
      if (chooser == null) chooser = createChooser();
      chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
      int r = chooser.showDialog(this, null);
      if (r != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) return;
      file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    }

    /**
     * For obstacles added to the program:
     * Simple parsing of relevant data into txt file for easy reading.
     * Rows will be written like so:
     * 
     * 50 25 b
     * 51 25 b
     * 52 25 b
     * 34 28 n
     * .
     * .
     * 
     * Column, followed by row, followed by type of obstacle.
     * Assumption: Only one obstacle per cell. Should be a relatively simple extension for multiple obstacles per cell.
     */

    try {

        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(file), "utf-8"));
        for(int i = 0; i < obstacles.size(); i++)
        {
            Cell currentCell = obstacles.get(i);
            writer.write(Integer.toString(currentCell.c));
            writer.write(" ");
            writer.write(Integer.toString(currentCell.r));
            writer.write(" ");

            if(currentCell.isBlocked())
                writer.write(blockedChar);
            else if(currentCell.isGoal())
                writer.write(goalChar);
            else if(currentCell.hasNest())
                writer.write(nestChar);
            writer.write("\n");
        }
        writer.close();
    }
```

how do i take in arraylist and file in the parameter of my save map method? when i take it in like this, an error happens saying that file is not resolve as a variable and Arraylist are not resolve as variables.

```
    item = menu.add(new JMenuItem("Save Map..."));
        item.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                AntsControlPanel.this.savemap(file,ArrayList<Cell> obstacles); } } 
        );
```

here is the part where i declare file and arraylist.

```
public class AntsControlPanel extends JPanel{


private Ants ants;
private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
private JButton timerButton = new JButton("\u25BA");
private JSlider speedSlider;
private JComboBox patternComboBox;
private JComboBox sizeComboBox;
private JTextField   stat    = null;
private JFileChooser chooser = null; 
private File         curr    = null;
private File file = null;
private TSP tsp  = null;
ArrayList<Cell> obstacles = new ArrayList<Cell>();
private final AdvancedControlPanel advancedPanel;
private final String blockedChar = "b";
private final String goalChar = "g";
private final String nestChar = "n";
```

Comment: Where do you declare/initialize `file`? Same for `obstacles`. You can do that in the method call but you would need to use the `new` keyword to actually make the objects first.

Comment: @Takendarkk i declared file and arraylist at the start of my class. private File file = null;ArrayList<Cell> obstacles = new ArrayList<Cell>(); but i still have the error Arraylist and obstacles cannot be resolve as a variable

Comment: In the same class as whatever `item` is? Show that portion since it is relevant to the problem in question.

Comment: @Takendarkk which portion?? whatever item is<cell>?

Comment: The part where you declare/initialize `file` and `obstacles`.

Comment: @Tekendarkk ok the part where i declare file and obstacles is in my editted code.

Comment: Well `obstacles` looks ok, except when you use it in the method call you need to remove the `ArrayList<Cell>` part. Just put `obstacles`. Also, your `file` is null so it wouldn't be doing much anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to call savemap,
use

```
 AntsControlPanel.this.savemap(file,obstacles);
```

at the place of

```
 AntsControlPanel.this.savemap(file,ArrayList<Cell> obstacles);
```

Comment: Although what you say is correct, this wouldn't solve the problem in question.

Comment: just one little step towards the goal ;)

Comment: @Min REN hmm i have the problem that when i save my file now. there is no content in it.

Comment: @Takendarkk hmm i have the problem that when i save my file now. there is no content in it.

Comment: Hence the reason this is not an answer to your question. Don't accept an answer when it doesn't solve the problem. Since what you now have is a new problem, post a new question or search this site for other similar duplicates.